# Importing csv data from Storage to Cloud SQL not working - status always "pending"

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-sql

I am new to java (I have experience with `C#` though)

Sadly, I inherited a terrible project (the code is terrible) and what I need to accomplish is to import some csv files into Cloud SQL

So there's a WS which runs this task, apparently the dev followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/import#examples) to import data. But it is not working. Here's the code (Essential parts, actually it is longer and more ugly)

```
    InstancesImportRequest requestBody = new InstancesImportRequest();
        ImportContext ic = new  ImportContext();
        ic.setKind("sql#importContext");
        ic.setFileType("csv");
        ic.setUri(bucketPath);
        ic.setDatabase(CLOUD_SQL_DATABASE);
        CsvImportOptions csv = new CsvImportOptions();
        csv.setTable(tablename);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        // here there is some code that populates the list with the columns
        csv.setColumns(list);
        ic.setCsvImportOptions(csv);
        requestBody.setImportContext(ic);
SQLAdmin sqlAdminService = createSqlAdminService();
     SQLAdmin.Instances.SQLAdminImport request = sqlAdminService.instances().sqladminImport(project, instance, requestBody);
    Operation response = request.execute();
    System.out.println("Executed : Going to sleep.>"+response.getStatus());
        int c = 1;
        while(!response.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Done")){
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            System.out.println("sleeped enough >"+response.getStatus());
            c++;
            if(c==50){
                System.out.println("timeout?");
                break;
            }
        }
public static SQLAdmin createSqlAdminService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
        if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
          credential =
              credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
        }

        return new SQLAdmin.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
            .setApplicationName("Google-SQLAdminSample/0.1")
            .build();
      }
```

I am not quite sure how response should be treated, it seems it is an async request. Either way, I always get status `Pending`; it seems it is not even start to executing.

Of course it ends timing out. What is wrong here, why the requests never starts ? I couldn't find any actual example on the internet about using this java sdk to import files, except the link I gave above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the thing is that the response object is static, so it will always return "Pending" as the initial status since it is a string in the object - it is not actually being updated.

To get the actual status, you have to requested it to google using the sdk. I did something like this (it will be better to use a smaller sleep time, and make it grow as you try more times)

```
SQLAdmin.Instances.SQLAdminImport request = sqlAdminService.instances().sqladminImport(CLOUD_PROJECT, CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE, requestBody);
        // execution of our import request
        Operation response = request.execute();
        int tried = 0;
        Operation statusOperation;
        do {
            // sleep one minute
            Thread.sleep(60000);
            // here we are requesting the status of our operation. Name is actually the unique identifier
            Get requestStatus = sqlAdminService.operations().get(CLOUD_PROJECT, response.getName());
            statusOperation = requestStatus.execute();
            tried++;
            System.out.println("status is: " + statusOperation.getStatus());
        } while(!statusOperation.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("DONE") && tried < 10);
        if (!statusOperation.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("DONE")) {
            throw new Exception("import failed: Timeout");
        }
```